# Contact form 7 failing on production server

Tags: php, wordpress, email, contact-form-7

I have a Wordpress site using contact form 7 to handle a couple of form submissions.

All works fine locally but when I deploy to production I get an error failing to send email and get the error `There was an error trying to send your message. Please try again later.`

I am using the exact same settings except for my `from` field which I have marketing@ email address so that the email domain name matches the site domain name.

Is there any way to check the error logs to get more information as to why it is failing?

Comment: Does the emailaddress exist on the production server? Did you change the IP if using IP instead of hostname?

Comment: The email address does exist. And I have tried a few different ones just in case. I am hosting on Google App Engine which may have something to do with it?

Comment: I am not familiar with Google App Engine, could you show the log **within code tags**?

Comment: @YvanWatchman sorry, show what log?

Comment: /var/log/apache2/error_log or on CentOS /var/log/apache2/error_log

Answer (score 1):

To see if Wordpress is generating some error you can can set

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);

define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);

define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
```

in wp_config, and Wordpress will generate a `debug.log` in `wp-content` folder with any error or notice that could be generated.

Don't forget to turn everything off after you finish debugging.